# Which of these is correct? -- question involving helping verbs (I think)

Tags: grammar, verbs

I have no idea how to explain why I generally think well, without having my explanation seem contrived

I have no idea how to explain why I generally think well, without my explanation seeming contrived

Comment: The second sentence is the correct one, though I wonder if this question would be more suited for English Language Learners.

Comment: They do not mean the same.

Comment: I disagree with *both* the above comments, *and* with the (currently) three closevotes saying this is "proofreading". The fact that (presumably, *competent*) speakers can have such different perspectives seems in and of itself sufficient evidence that there's something to be explored here.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these would be correct, depending upon point of view. The second, without the helping verb focuses more on the point of view of the speaker. It at least approached the notion that the speaker (I) finds the explanation contrived. On the other hand, the first version, with the helping verb, focuses more on the point of view of someone other than the speaker. If the speaker tries to explain, some other party will think the explanation is contrived.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one is best, but more importantly, your meaning is unclear... Unless it is explained elsewhere in your writing, describing yourself as one who can *think well* is confusing to the reader.  Are you referring to your accelerated intellectual abilities?  If so, I suggest replacing the words "why I think well" in the following way...

I have no idea how to explain *my advanced reasoning skills* without my explanation *sounding* contrived.

Note:  No comma is needed in this sentence, and I replaced *seeming* with *sounding*....  I also removed the word "generally," a word that is considered unnecessary, in *general*.      ;)

Comment: Second of two can only be 'better' not 'best.' :)